# Reduce Stock Based on Custom Variation Field Rather than Attribute (Working Script)

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, variables, fatal-error

I currently have a script that works perfectly. The issue is, I want to use the value in a custom field I have created for my variations rather than an attribute. See code:

```
// reduce stock based on 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // 'pa_weight' attribute value is "15 grams" - keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    return $quantity;
}
```

I have tried replacing

`$term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');`

With

`$term_name = $product->get_post_meta('custom_field', true);`

And similar things, but keep getting undefined method errors and the like. It is as though the value isn't being properly called.

Any idea? TIA.

Comment: Try `$product->get_meta( 'custom_field', true )`..

Comment: I love you. Honestly and truly. I owe you my firstborn child.

I spent hours racking my brain, banging my head against the wall yesterday. I searched the internet endlessly and came up empty-handed. I ran var_dumps and error logs... nothing.

Thank you Sally! I love you!

Comment: Well, I'd love you too if you upvote the comment.. :D I mean, I'm just glad it helped. :)

Comment: I can't Sally, I don't have the ability or I'd give you 1000 up-votes.

Comment: Actually, I believe you can - [voting privilege](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is awarded at 15 reputation point. So try clicking on the "up" arrow? :)